# Cannot link static library from Makefile

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, static-libraries

I build a static library. The problem is that I can't link it from my Makefile

```
TARGET  =       AR1020
CC      =       gcc
CFLAGS  =       -Wall -std=c99 -I./inc/
LINKER  =       gcc -o
LFLAGS  =       -Wall -static -I./inc/


SRCDIR  =       src
INCDIR  =       inc
OBJDIR  =       obj
BINDIR  =       bin

LIBDIR  =       ./lib
LIBFLAG =       -li2c


SOURCES         :=      $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
INCLUDES        :=      $(wildcard $(INCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS         :=      $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm              =       rm -f

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        @$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) -L$(LIBDIR) $(LIBFLAG) $(OBJECTS)
        @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
        @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
        @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        @$(rm) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"

.PHONY: remove
remove: clean
        @$(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
        @echo "Exacutable removed!"
```

My tree is:

```
|-- bin
|-- inc
|   |-- color.h
|   |-- EXT.h
|   |-- EXT.h~
|   |-- gpio_lib.h
|   `-- test.h
|-- lib
|   |-- i2c.c
|   |-- i2c.o
|   `-- libi2c.a
|-- Makefile
|-- obj
|   |-- AR1020.o
|   |-- gpio_lib.o
|   |-- gpio.o
|   `-- test.o
`-- src
    |-- AR1020.c
    |-- gpio_lib.c
    `-- libi2c.a
```

I want to link libi2c.a but I'm getting the error "undefined reference to '.....'. If I compile it manually like:

```
gcc src/AR1020.c lib/libi2c.a
```

Everything compiles as it should be. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Libraries you want to link in needs to come after the object files that uses anything in those libraries, so

```
@$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) -L$(LIBDIR) $(LIBFLAG) $(OBJECTS)
```

should be

```
@$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) -L$(LIBDIR)  $(OBJECTS) $(LIBFLAG)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a useful article about linking libraries. http://docencia.ac.upc.edu/FIB/USO/Bibliografia/unix-c-libraries.html

> The linker checks each file in turn. If it is an object file, it is being placed fully into the executable file. If it is a library, the linker checks to see if any symbols referenced (i.e. used) in the previous object files but not defined (i.e. contained) in them, are in the library. If such a symbol is found, the whole object file from the library that contains the symbol - is being added to the executable file. This process continues until all object files and libraries on the command line were processed.
>
> Note that object files found on the command line are always fully included in the executable file, so the order of mentioning them does not really matter. Thus, a good rule is to always mention the libraries after all object files